# Save state of BaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, state, baseadapter

I am using an external card library ([gabrielemariotti cardlib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)) in my app.
I have two activities too.

1. For example, in Main activity I added two-three cards
2. Then I entered in one of them (went to ProductCard Activity)
3. If I pushed "back" - I see the normal situation in Main Activity (all two cards are there). But if I save button "OK" (to call Intent from ProductCard Activity to Main Activity) I see that only one card exists.

I see that I have some problem with savedInstanceState, but I don't understand how to save my CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter in it. Can you help me to understand how to save all cards in Main Activity when I returned from another activities?
Thank you

```
package com.example.dmitry.myfoodbasket;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.cards.actions.BaseSupplementalAction;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.cards.actions.IconSupplementalAction;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.cards.material.MaterialLargeImageCard;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardHeader;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.recyclerview.internal.CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.recyclerview.view.CardRecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    ArrayList<BaseSupplementalAction> actions;
    ArrayList<Card> cards;
    MaterialLargeImageCard card;
    CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter mCardArrayAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
                cards.add(card);
                mCardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        card =
                MaterialLargeImageCard.with(this)
                        .setTextOverImage("Italian Beaches")
                        .useDrawableId(R.drawable.im_beach)
                        .setupSupplementalActions(R.layout.carddemo_native_material_supplemental_actions_large_icon,actions )
                        .build();
        cards.add(card);
        card.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProductCard.class);
                startActivity(intent);




            }});

        actions = new ArrayList<BaseSupplementalAction>();

        IconSupplementalAction t1 = new IconSupplementalAction(this, R.id.ic1);
        t1.setOnActionClickListener(new BaseSupplementalAction.OnActionClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Click on Text SHARE ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        actions.add(t1);

        IconSupplementalAction t2 = new IconSupplementalAction(this, R.id.ic2);
        t2.setOnActionClickListener(new BaseSupplementalAction.OnActionClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," Click on Text LEARN ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        actions.add(t2);

        IconSupplementalAction t3 = new IconSupplementalAction(this, R.id.ic3);
        t3.setOnActionClickListener(new BaseSupplementalAction.OnActionClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Карточка удалена ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cards.remove(card);
                mCardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        actions.add(t3);


        mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter(this, cards);
        CardRecyclerView mRecyclerView = (CardRecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.carddemo_recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}


package com.example.dmitry.myfoodbasket;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;



/**
 * Created by Dmitry on 27.10.2015.
 */
public class ProductCard extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    Button moneyOk_readylist;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_card);
        moneyOk_readylist=(Button)findViewById(R.id.moneyOk_readylist);
        moneyOk_readylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ProductCard.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```